# Python/Docker - ModuleNotFoundError: No module named

Tags: python, python-3.x, docker, python-import

I tried different solution found on SO. From importing `sys` to doing different manipulation but I cannot figure it out how to make thing work.

Here my structure folder :

```
├── __init__.py
├── config
│   └── airflow.cfg
├── dags
│   ├── __init__.py
│   └── inscription.py
├── docker-compose.yml
├── extra
│   ├── __init__.py
│   └── sql_statements.py
├── plugins
│   ├── __init__.py
│   └── operators
│       ├── __init__.py
│       ├── __pycache__
│       ├── has_rows.py
│       └── s3_to_redshift.py
└── requirements.txt
```

All `__ini__.py` are empty.

When I import inside `dags/inscription.py` the code I have in `extra/sql_statements.py` by doing `from extra.sql_statements import *`, My IDE (PyCharm) doing scream at me, but when I run the project with docker it fails.

```
[2019-10-07 07:35:12,286] {{__init__.py:416}} ERROR - Failed to import: /usr/local/airflow/dags/inscription.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/airflow/models/__init__.py", line 413, in process_file
    m = imp.load_source(mod_name, filepath)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/imp.py", line 172, in load_source
    module = _load(spec)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 684, in _load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 665, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 678, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/usr/local/airflow/dags/inscription.py", line 8, in <module>
    from extra.sql_statements import *
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'extra'
```

I don't understand because some other python script I have seems to work that way but I run them without docker. I want to understand what happend here.