# Python no module named <foldername> with docker setup

Tags: python, docker, namespaces

I have a python project running in a docker container.

My development environment is structured as follows:

```
-- app
---- Module1
------ ClassM1.py
---- Module2
----- ClassM2.py
---- main.py
-- docker-compose.yml
```

and in my compose file I am mounting ./app/:/app/

While developing (in PyCharm) I am using this import line without problems in the main.py:

```
from app.Module1.ClassM1 import ClassM1
from app.Module1.ClassM2 import ClassM2
```

but when I deploy my code in my container I get

> "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'app'"

What I already tried:

- create an `__init__.py` in the root
- `export PYTHONPATH=.`
- import sys and do an sys.path.append("./")

I've found a similar question but without answers: [Python/Docker - ModuleNotFoundError: No module named](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58265270/python-docker-modulenotfounderror-no-module-named)

Comment: The volume mount you describe can lead to some inconsistencies; does deleting it help at all?  What is in your `Dockerfile` and `docker-compose.yml` files?

Comment: My compose is just a simple
 
    `build: .
    volumes:
      - ./app/:/app/`


and the Dockerfile sets the workdir to /app

Comment: Are you building an image that contains your code at all; is the Dockerfile literally just a `FROM` and a `WORKDIR` line?  If the goal of this setup is to run code that exists only on your host without using Docker's image system or other features, then using a plain Python virtual environment without Docker might be easier.

Comment: Try add `ENV PYTHONPATH=.:$PYTHONPATH` and `WORKDIR /apps` into Dockerfile,  and in compose file change mounting to  `./app:/apps/app`

Comment: Sadly I thought it had fixed the problem...
The thing is, this all runs  as a cronjob. Problem is, to get it working my cron line looks like this ````cd /app && /usr/local/bin/python3 main.py```` with main.py located in /apps/app. The import of ClassM1.py in main.py works (without app. in front of it), BUT in ClassM1.py I also need to import ClassM2.py so I do ````from app.ClassM2 import ClassM2````but is says again app not found

Comment: If I run the cron line directly in the terminal it works fine. I also print out the cwd right at the start, in both cases it states "/app". But the one started via cron always has this ModuleNotFoundError. Why?!

Answer (score 0):

By default, It shouldn't work outside docker as well. When importing a file, Python only searches the directory that the entry-point script is running from and sys.path which includes locations such as the package installation directory (it's actually a little more complex than this, but this covers most cases).

You can use this:

```
from Module1.ClassM1 import ClassM1
from Module2.ClassM2 import ClassM2
```

PS: there is typo in your code

```
from app.Module1.ClassM2 import ClassM2 -> from app.Module2.ClassM2 import ClassM2
```

Comment: I could remove the app. in my main.py but now my problem is that in ClassM1 I am using ClassM2, but here again I have the ModuleNotFound error...
The typo was because I wrote the pseudo code by hand. My correct modules are a little bit more complex structured